# Socket.js not working with RaspberryPi

Tags: javascript, python, flask, socket.io, raspberry-pi

I am trying to create a flask application to automatic generator of random string. I would like to implement with socket.js. So everything going nice except the connection with the of socket. It's worked with the PC but not working with raspberry Pi.

Here is the files structure

```
|-- app.py
|-- static
|   `-- js
|       |-- ajax.js
|       |-- hello_world.js
|       `-- Socket.js
`-- templates
        `-- hello_world.html
```

Here is my code samples.

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO, emit
import random
import string

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

class AppObject():

    def __init__(self):
        self.app = Flask(__name__)
        self.socketio = SocketIO(self.app)

    @app.route('/')
    def Hello():
        global appObject
        sampleText = appObject.stringGen()
        return render_template('hello_world.html', name=sampleText)

    def stringGen(self):
        chars = "".join( [random.choice(string.letters) for i in xrange(15)] )
        return chars

if __name__ == '__main__':
    appObject = AppObject()
    appObject.socketio.run(app,host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

**hello_world.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
namespace = '/test';
var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + namespace);
var b1 = document.getElementById('text-id');

});
```

**hello_world.html**

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <script src="static/js/ajax.js"></script>
   <script src="static/js/hello_world.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/Socket.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

</head>

   {% if name %}
   <h1 id="text-id"> {{ name }}!</h1>
   {% else %}
   <h1>Hello World!</h1>
   {% endif %}
</html>
```

Here is my error [image]

When i implementing all these i am  getting an error `TypeError: a.transport is null` in socket.js. And it's point to the line which is used to connect socket in JavaScript (`var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + namespace);` ). I checked with another PC via ssh.But it's worked fine I don't know why. Please help to solve this issue.
Thank you.

Comment: Please add the versions of Flask-SocketIO and the Javascript client that you are using.

Comment: Flask-SocketIO==1.1, and JavaScript client is socket.io client.